# How can I change my Gamertag?

Tags: xbox-network

I made an Xbox Account and I set my Bio and Moto and other stuff, but I logged in using my Outlook account and it automatically generated "ThirstyBench414" as my Gamertag.

How can I modify it? I am using Windows, and not an Xbox.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page](https://support.xbox.com/en-GB/my-account/manage-gamertag-and-profile/change-xbox-live-gamertag), "you can easily change your Xbox Live gamertag. If your gamertag was created for you during your initial Xbox Live sign-up (meaning you did not choose your gamertag), you can change the gamertag one time for free."

To do this using a web browser (on PC):

- In a web browser, go to `Change gamertag` at [account.xbox.com](https://account.xbox.com) (shown in image, below).
- Sign in using the Microsoft account email address and password associated with your gamertag.
- Enter your new gamertag and click `Check Availability`.
- Once you find an available gamertag that you want, click `Claim it!` (You only get one free claim, so be sure)

Example of US region site (may vary):
[image: account.xbox.com - US region]

Comment: Also note that you can set a "real name", where you put a different name (intended to be your actual name) for friends to see you as.

Comment: Don't rely entirely on the image, either. The site you go to depends on your region, and may look different.

Comment: I can't decide if it's better to have a possibly unreliable image, or to have no image. Could remove it? @Timelord64

Comment: I would recommend adding, just above the image, "this is what you will see if you log in in america, but the site may look differant in differant regions", or something of that like.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not entirely sure what @TZHX means? It's supported behavior, etc.

Comment: Well, when I changed my gamertag it charged me, despite having not changed it before and the screen looking exactly as your picture. That's what I meant.

Comment: Confirming that it did try to charge me. Naturally, I wasn't stupid enough to click "purchase" without looking at the cost. But as I said, I was never given an automated username.

Comment: I believe you've removed the comment where you said that. Continuity errors! I suspect that contacting support will sort it, assuming you're both right in thinking that you've not done it before (given the documented "is free for x" stuff) - if you actually wanted to go through with it. Did you not change tag, then, @Timelord64?

Comment: it does, in fact, state directly above that "your first is free". I assume this applys to people that had to generate an ID because their requested ID was taken. I commonly go by the username "Gnemlock", so this is never a problem for me :P I deleted my comment saying it worked for me, as I found out after that it had not. sorry for any confusion

Comment: @Jeeva Uh oh... that should not have happened.
It appears you have found a glitch in the system. Please try again later. i clicked and error what i can do!?

Comment: @Jeeva theres an error when link is clicked http://imgur.com/ALsmak2

Comment: Hi @game-on-asus - I see from the URL that it has redirected you to language "lt-LT". Based on a quick Google, that looks like it might be Lithuanian. Lithuania isn't a supported country for Xbox Live etc, (though obviously this is on PC), it seems to me that it might be affecting your ability to log in on Xbox.com. If I'm wrong, please let me know. You may need to contact Support in order to change this. https://xbox.uservoice.com/forums/251649-memberships-accounts/suggestions/6032275-add-lithuania-and-other-baltic-states-to-support http://www.xbox.com/en-gb/live/countries

Answer (score 1):

I tried and it didn't work. The html div with the submit to actually change it is hidden.
[image: hidden div with gamertag submit]

So I changed the hidden div but that didn't work either. The redirect is to the profile page and the gamertag is still the same, even after signing in again.

[image: gamertag submit]

Comment: So today I tried it again, this time I used an iMac with Yosemite. Have to check at home if it works on Windows. 

But it isn't as free as the content says it is. When you 'claim it' you'll get a pop-up claiming it's either 10$ or 10€ to change your gamertag.

Comment: I've [read](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/xbox_one_support/f/4268/p/2012583/5339532.aspx#5339532) that you can only change your gamertag if you have chosen a random gamertag or within 30 days of creating your account. So the 'You can change it once for free' here is false advertising.

Comment: i can change it for free for some reason